# Magento 2: How to get related product custom option using graphQl?

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, product-collection, graphql

I want to get related products with **custom option** data using **GraphQl**. I am using the below **GraphQl query** to get related product custom options data. can anyone help with this?

```
{
  products(filter: {sku: {eq: "24-WG09"}}) {
    items {
      id
      name
      special_price
      price {
        regularPrice {
          amount {
            value
          }
        }
      }
      related_products {
        id
        name  
        url_key
        image {
          label
          url
        }
        price {
          regularPrice {
            amount {
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need more detail.